# How to read n bytes of a file in QT C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

Hi im new to Qt and im trying to read for example the first 4 bytes of my .txt file and show it. I've been searching and figure that QbyteArray may help me best in this situation. so I really like to know how can i read the first 4 bytes of my file with QbyteArray? (appreciate if u write any example code)

Comment: QFile::read(4) will return a QByteArray with 4 bytes of data from the file in it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#read-1

Comment: Yeah that was the correct way. thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code contains something like this:

```
QFile file{ "path/to/file.txt" };
```

- You can read a number of bytes from a file with `file.read(n)`, assuming n to be a number of bytes. you can also use `file.readAll()` to get the entire thing
- for more advanced input/output operations, you can use the `QTextStream` class as such:

  `QFile file { "path/to/file.txt" };`

  `QTextStream stream { &file };`
  *(This is a stream that can read and write data to the provided device, here, a file.)*

For more info, see here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html for QFile

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextstream.html for QTextStream